# JavaFX - Binding Slider to Button's Disable Property

Tags: button, javafx, binding, slider

I'm trying to enable a Button only if the Slider's Thumb goes over new value (or position).

Below is the window with its initial situation:

[image]

As soon I start to drag the Thumb the Button is activated, even the Thumb's not over new value (activated even between values):

[image]

If I abort the drag operation (release mouse button) and the Thumb returns to the initial position (or value), the Button don't disabled.

[image]

The code:

```
private void configSldFontSize() {
    
    sldFontSize.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        if (oldValue == newValue) {
            btnApply.setDisable(true);
        } else {
            btnApply.setDisable(false);
        }

    });

}
```

Configuration error maybe ?

```
private void setUpSlrFontSize() {

    sldFontSize.setMin(0);
    sldFontSize.setMax(FontSize.values().length - 1);
    sldFontSize.setValue(viewFactory.getFontSize().ordinal());
    sldFontSize.setMajorTickUnit(1);
    sldFontSize.setMinorTickCount(0);
    sldFontSize.setBlockIncrement(1);
    sldFontSize.setSnapToTicks(true);
    sldFontSize.setShowTickMarks(true);
    sldFontSize.setShowTickLabels(true);
    sldFontSize.setLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Double>() {

        @Override
        public Double fromString(String arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(Double obj) {
            int i = obj.intValue();
            return FontSize.values()[i].toString();
        }

    });

}
```

**======= SMALL CODE IMPLEMENTATION TO REPLICATE CONDITION ==========**

**ATTENTION:**

I'm using Java 11 (with Java 8 it's not necessary, I guess). So it's may be necessary to include following line in "Run Configurations".

[image]

In Package Explorer: right mouse button on "Main.Java => Run As => Run Configurations...", select "(x) = Arguments" tab and put the line as image below, **CHANGING THE PATH TO YOUR JAVAFX LIB FOLDER**.

[image]

**CODE**
Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        
        Button btnApply = new Button("Apply");
        btnApply.setDisable(true);
        
        Slider sldFontSize = new Slider();
        sldFontSize.setMin(0);
        sldFontSize.setMax(2);
        sldFontSize.setValue(1);
        sldFontSize.setMajorTickUnit(1);
        sldFontSize.setMinorTickCount(0);
        sldFontSize.setBlockIncrement(1);
        sldFontSize.setSnapToTicks(true);
        sldFontSize.setShowTickMarks(true);
        sldFontSize.setShowTickLabels(true);
        
        sldFontSize.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (oldValue == newValue) {
                btnApply.setDisable(true);
            } else {
                btnApply.setDisable(false);
            }

        });
        
        root.getChildren().addAll(sldFontSize, btnApply);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,200,100);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can create a separate property that represents the actual value you want from the slider, and then register a listener with that property. Note that change listeners are only notified when the value actually changes, so the `if (oldValue==newValue)` in your listener will always be false.

In this case, since the value of interest is just the result of casting the slider's value to an `int`, you can just bind an `IntegerProperty` to the slider value:

```
        IntegerProperty intValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        intValue.bind(sldFontSize.valueProperty());

        intValue.addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> btnApply.setDisable(false));
```

More generally, create a custom binding or register a listener with `sldFontSize.valueProperty()` that updates your other property. E.g. using your `FontSize`, which I think is an `enum`:

```
ObjectProperty<FontSize> fontSizeProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
fontSizeProperty.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
    () -> FontSize.value()[(int) sldFontSize.getValue()],
    sldFontSize.valueProperty()));
fontSizeProperty.addListener((obs, oldFontSize, newFontSize) -> btnApply.setDisable(false));
```

For more precision, you can implement rounding instead of simply casting, etc. You might also want to save the "last applied value" and compare against that when deciding whether or not to disable/enable the button, etc.

Putting all that together you get something like:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            
            IntegerProperty lastSavedFontSize = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
            IntegerProperty sldIntValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

            Button btnApply = new Button("Apply");
            btnApply.setOnAction(e -> lastSavedFontSize.set(sldIntValue.get()));
            btnApply.disableProperty().bind(sldIntValue.isEqualTo(lastSavedFontSize));

            Slider sldFontSize = new Slider();
            sldFontSize.setMin(0);
            sldFontSize.setMax(2);
            sldFontSize.setValue(lastSavedFontSize.get());
            sldFontSize.setMajorTickUnit(1);
            sldFontSize.setMinorTickCount(0);
            sldFontSize.setBlockIncrement(1);
            sldFontSize.setSnapToTicks(true);
            sldFontSize.setShowTickMarks(true);
            sldFontSize.setShowTickLabels(true);
            
            sldIntValue.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                    () ->(int) Math.round(sldFontSize.getValue()), 
                    sldFontSize.valueProperty()));


            root.getChildren().addAll(sldFontSize, btnApply);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

Another approach entirely is to make use of the slider's `valueChangingProperty()`. This boolean property is true if and only if the user is currently in the process of changing the value. Note that, in some circumstances, the `valueChangingProperty()` can become false *before* the final value of the slider is set, so it's safest to listen to both properties. Here's a version using this approach:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            
            IntegerProperty lastSavedFontSize = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

            Button btnApply = new Button("Apply");
            btnApply.setDisable(true);  


            Slider sldFontSize = new Slider();
            sldFontSize.setMin(0);
            sldFontSize.setMax(2);
            sldFontSize.setValue(lastSavedFontSize.get());
            sldFontSize.setMajorTickUnit(1);
            sldFontSize.setMinorTickCount(0);
            sldFontSize.setBlockIncrement(1);
            sldFontSize.setSnapToTicks(true);
            sldFontSize.setShowTickMarks(true);
            sldFontSize.setShowTickLabels(true);

            btnApply.setOnAction(e -> {
                // apply change, and do
                lastSavedFontSize.set((int) sldFontSize.getValue());
            });
            
            ChangeListener<Object> sliderListener = (obs, oldV, newV) -> {
                if (!sldFontSize.isValueChanging()) {
                    btnApply.setDisable((int)sldFontSize.getValue() == lastSavedFontSize.get());
                }
            };

            sldFontSize.valueProperty().addListener(sliderListener);
            sldFontSize.valueChangingProperty().addListener(sliderListener);
            lastSavedFontSize.addListener(sliderListener);

            root.getChildren().addAll(sldFontSize, btnApply);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you move the slider the value changes for each mouse movement.
[image]
So comparing `oldValue` and `newValue` from listener will not work. You need another strategy.

You can save default value on initialization and compare current value with default when the mouse is released:

```
sldFontSize.setOnMouseReleased(event -> btnApply.setDisable(sldFontSize.getValue() == defaultValue));
```

Full code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = new VBox();

            Button btnApply = new Button("Apply");
            btnApply.setDisable(true);

            Slider sldFontSize = new Slider();
            sldFontSize.setMin(0);
            sldFontSize.setMax(2);
            sldFontSize.setValue(1);
            sldFontSize.setMajorTickUnit(1);
            sldFontSize.setMinorTickCount(0);
            sldFontSize.setBlockIncrement(1);
            sldFontSize.setSnapToTicks(true);
            sldFontSize.setShowTickMarks(true);
            sldFontSize.setShowTickLabels(true);

            double defaultValue = sldFontSize.getValue();
            sldFontSize.setOnMouseReleased(event -> btnApply.setDisable(sldFontSize.getValue() == defaultValue));

            root.getChildren().addAll(sldFontSize, btnApply);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. This relies on undocumented behavior; namely that the value is updated *before* the mouse released event is propagated to the listener. There's no guarantee this will be true, even if it works in the current JavaFX release (it seems particularly fragile, for example, for the user clicking on the slider track). 2. The functionality completely breaks if the user changes the slider value using the keyboard (or, I assume, with assistive technologies).